# whats secure_mode (miniupnpd.conf)

Tags: linux, networking

I am trying to set miniupnpd (UPnP server), but please point out if you understand miniupnpd.conf secure_mode.

When set to secure_mode = yes, miniupnpd will assign the IP address of the local network to the client.

that's ok?

## secure_mode

There is a comment in miniupnpd.conf as follows:

https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/miniupnpd/miniupnpd.conf

```
# Secure Mode, UPnP clients can only add mappings to their own IP
#secure_mode=yes
secure_mode=no
```

I understood that secure_mode is the one that assigns the local IP address to the client.

## background

Why did I ask a question like this, Google search for secure_mode hit information about vulnerability.

[CVE-2016-10185](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-10185)

> An issue was discovered on the D-Link DWR-932B router. A secure_mode=no line exists in /var/miniupnpd.conf.

Although it seems to be a D-Link limited router vulnerability, the setting secure_mode = no is the default setting in miniupnpd.conf.

I read [the reproduction code](https://pierrekim.github.io/blog/2016-09-28-dlink-dwr-932b-lte-routers-vulnerabilities.html#security-removed-in-upnp). this vulnerability seems to be "access restriction by IP address is not done and secure_mode = no".

Access restrictions are as follows.

```
allow 1024-65535 192.168.0.0/24 1024-65535
deny 0-65535 0.0.0.0/0 0-65535
```

## question

CVE-2016-10185 is written only as "Do not write secure_mode = no", but it is not so, as it is not restricting access.

That is, if secure_mode = yes, miniupnpd will assign the IP address of the local network to the client. Therefore, I understanding that you can restrict access even if secure_mode = no is set. that's ok?

Answer (score 4):

> miniupnpd will assign the IP address of the local network to the client.

No, UPnP doesn't assign IP addresses (DHCP does that). UPnP in this context adds *mappings*, firewall rules that allows connections through NAT. This in general is a dangerous idea, whether it's in `secure_mode` or not:

- Chris Hoffman, [Is UPnP a Security Risk?](https://www.howtogeek.com/122487/htg-explains-is-upnp-a-security-risk/)
- Andy Green, [What is UPnP & Why is it Dangerous?](https://blog.varonis.com/what-is-upnp/)

> ```
> # Secure Mode, UPnP clients can only add mappings to their own IP
> ```

While the access restrictions disallows connections to *low ports* (system or well-known ports, <1024) on the local network, it doesn't protect anything listening on other ports. The `secure_mode = yes` checks that the client is requesting a firewall rule for itself.

Scenario with `secure_mode = no`:

1. Someone orders a [Smart Dishwasher](https://www.lifewire.com/smart-dishwasher-4159822) from China, embedded with a malware. It's connected to your company network using WiFi and has DHCP assigned IP address `192.168.0.196`.
2. You have an internal web server on alternative HTTP port 8080, `http://192.168.0.20:8080/`.
3. The dishwasher requests your miniupnpd to allow access to `192.168.0.20:8080`.
4. Everyone has access to your internal web server.

With `secure_mode = yes` the diswasher has to do something more active, e.g. perform as a reverse proxy or actually steal the data and send it away. The dishwasher could also be any BYOD device!

Comment: thanks! UPnP is very dangerous ;-( I read miniupnpd source code, where used secure_mode [miniupnpd/upnpsoap.c](https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/blob/master/miniupnpd/upnpsoap.c#L464) . just check NewInternalAddress. and Is client exist localnetwork. so, even if `secure_mode = yes` set, miniupnpd can't prevent atack by Malicious client (e.g. malware) :-(

Comment: It's always better to forward necessary ports manually.